# Getting "not a statement when trying to get an object from hashmap

Tags: java, object, hashmap

I am getting an error when I try to get an object from a hashmap so that I can use it. when I use this sentence:

```
                    Linje 1=linjerMap.get(linjeList[i]);
```

where Linje is the Object, 1 is the wanted objectvariable, linjerMap is the hashmap and linjeList is the place where the name of the key to the object is stored.

The rest of the code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

class Oblig5{

    public static void main(String[] args){

    Planlegger starten=new Planlegger();
    starten.lesFil();

    }
}

class Planlegger{

    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
    HashMap<String, Linje> linjerMap=new HashMap<String, Linje>();
    HashMap<String, Stasjon> stasjonerMap=new HashMap<String, Stasjon>();

    void lesFil(){

        Linje linjer;
        Stasjon stasjoner;
        String linjeLest="";
        String aktuellLinje="";
        String linjeNummer="";
        char[] linjeNummerA;
        int linjeNummerInt=0;

        try{
            Scanner innFil=new Scanner(new File("Rutetabell.txt"));

            while(innFil.hasNextLine()){

                linjeLest=innFil.nextLine().toLowerCase();

                if(linjeLest.contains("linje")){
                    System.out.println("TESTILINJE");
                    //Bruker en string for linjenummeret her for å lette bruken av nummeret som key i HashMapen. 

                    linjeNummerInt=Integer.parseInt(linjeLest.replaceAll("[\\D]", ""));
                    // linjeNummerA[0]=linjeLest.split("*linje* ").charAt(0);
                    // linjeNummer=linjeNummer[0];
                    linjer=new Linje(linjeNummer);
                    aktuellLinje=linjeNummer;
                    linjerMap.put(linjeNummer, linjer); 

                }else{
                    System.out.println("TESTISTASJON");
                    //Dersom ikke objektet finnes i hashmapen for stasjoner allerede, så lages objektet og lagres i HashMapen. 
                    if(!stasjonerMap.containsKey(linjeLest)){
                        stasjonerMap.put(linjeLest, new Stasjon(linjeLest));
                    }
                    //Her henter jeg ut objektet vi lager over, og om det ikke lages fordi det allerede eksisterer så hentes det ut uansett.
                    stasjoner=stasjonerMap.get(linjeLest);
                    //Her brukes objektinformasjonen over til å registrere stasjonen i objektet
                    linjer=linjerMap.get(aktuellLinje);
                    linjer.registrerStasjoner(linjeLest, stasjoner);
                    stasjoner.registrerNyLinje(aktuellLinje, linjer);
                }       
            }
            innFil.close();
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Test");
        String sjekkHashmap=input.nextLine();
        if(stasjonerMap.containsKey(sjekkHashmap)){
            System.out.println("Det funker!");
        }
    }

    void beregnRuter(Stasjon fraSt, Stasjon tilSt){


    }

    void lesFraTil(){
        fraStasjon();
    }

    void fraStasjon(){

        boolean sjekkStasjon=true;
        while(sjekkStasjon){
            System.out.println("Vennligst tast inn fra-stasjonen: ");
            String startStasjon=input.next().toLowerCase();
            if(stasjonerMap.containsKey(startStasjon)){
                sjekkStasjon=false;
                tilStasjon(startStasjon);
            }else{
                System.out.println("Stasjon ikke funnet.");
                sjekkStasjon=true;
            }
        }
    }

    void tilStasjon(String startStasjon){

        boolean sjekkStasjon=true;
        while(sjekkStasjon){
            System.out.println("Vennligst tast inn til-stasjonen: ");
            String sluttStasjon=input.next().toLowerCase();
            if(stasjonerMap.containsKey(sluttStasjon)){
                sjekkStasjon=false;
                rutePlanlegger(startStasjon, sluttStasjon);
            }else{  
                System.out.println("Stasjon ikke funnet.");
                sjekkStasjon=true;
            }
        }
    }

    void rutePlanlegger(String startStasjon, String sluttStasjon){

        Stasjon til=stasjonerMap.get(startStasjon);
        Stasjon fra=stasjonerMap.get(sluttStasjon);
        int tilStasjonsTall, fraStasjonsTall;
        int retning;
        double tid= 0.0;
        String endeStasjonsNavn;

        tilStasjonsTall=0;
        fraStasjonsTall=0;

        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < list.size(); j++) {
                if(fra.linjeList[i].equals(til.linjeList[j])){
                    Linje 1=linjerMap.get(linjeList[i]);
                    retning=1.stasjonsNummer(startStasjon) - 1.stasjonsNummer(sluttStasjon);
                    endeStasjonsNavn=1.endestasjon(retning).stasjonsNavn;
                    System.out.println("Ta T-bane linje " + 1.linjeNummer + " fra " + startStasjon + " til " sluttStasjon + " i retning " + endeStasjonsNavn + ". Estimert reisetid: " + tid);



            }
        }
    }
}

class Linje{
    String linjeNummer="";
    HashMap<String, Stasjon> linjeStasjoner=new HashMap<String, Stasjon>();
    int antallStasjoner=0;
    int type=0;
    ArrayList<Stasjon> stasjonsList=new ArrayList<Stasjon>();

    int antall=stasjonsList.length();

    Linje(String linjeNummer){
        this.linjeNummer=linjeNummer;   
        if (linjeNummer<10){
            type=0;
        }else{
            type=1;
        }
    }



    void registrerStasjoner(String linjeLest, Stasjon stasjon){
        linjeStasjoner.put(linjeLest, stasjon);
        stasjonsList.add(stasjon);
        antallStasjoner++;
    }

    boolean inneholder(Stasjon stasjon){
        boolean sannhetsSjekk=true;
        if(stasjonsList.contains(stasjon)){
            sannhetsSjekk=true;
        }else{
                sannhetsSjekk=false;
        }
        return sannhetsSjekk;
    }

    Stasjon endestasjon(int retning) {                
        if (retning > 0) {
            return stasjoner[0];
        }

        return stasjoner[antall-1];
    }

    int stasjonsNummer (Stasjon s) {

        for (int i = 0; i < stasjonsList.length(); ++i) {
            if (stasjoner[i] == s) {
                return i;
            }
        }

        return -1;
    }          
}

class Stasjon{
    String stasjonNavn;
    Linje linje;
    HashMap <String, Linje> stasjonsLinjer=new HashMap<String, Linje>();
    ArrayList<Linje> linjeList=new ArrayList<Linje>();
    int teller=0;

    Stasjon(String linjeLest){
    this.stasjonNavn=linjeLest;
    }

    void registrerNyLinje(String aktuellLinje, Linje linje){
    stasjonsLinjer.put(aktuellLinje, linje);
    linjeList.add(linje);
    teller++;
    }
}

class Overgang{

        Linje l1, l2;
        Stasjon fra,til,bytte;
        Planlegger planlegger;




}
```

The error:

> oblig5.java:129: error: not a statement
>                                           Linje 1=linjerMap.get(linjeList[i]);
>                                           ^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't name a variable as a numeric literal (or start with any numeric digit).  Try

```
Linje one = linjerMap.get(linjeList[i]);
```

[Section 3.8 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8) covers what can be a legal identifier (emphasis mine):

> An identifier is an unlimited-length sequence of Java letters and Java digits, **the first of which must be a Java letter**.
>
> Identifier:
>
> > IdentifierChars but not a Keyword or BooleanLiteral or NullLiteral
>
> IdentifierChars:
>
> > JavaLetter
> >        IdentifierChars JavaLetterOrDigit
>
> JavaLetter:
>
> > any Unicode character that is a Java letter (see below)
>
> JavaLetterOrDigit:
>
> > any Unicode character that is a Java letter-or-digit (see below)
>
> A "Java letter" is a character for which the method Character.isJavaIdentifierStart(int) returns true.
>
> A "Java letter-or-digit" is a character for which the method Character.isJavaIdentifierPart(int) returns true.
>
> The "Java letters" include uppercase and lowercase ASCII Latin letters A-Z (\u0041-\u005a), and a-z (\u0061-\u007a), and, for historical reasons, the ASCII underscore (_, or \u005f) and dollar sign ($, or \u0024). The $ character should be used only in mechanically generated source code or, rarely, to access pre-existing names on legacy systems.
>
> The "Java digits" include the ASCII digits 0-9 (\u0030-\u0039).

Comment: Okay, thanks! Can I ask one more thing? I can't get the system.out.println in the same area to work? The one inside the nested for-loops and the if-statement. It tells me to add an ')', why is taht? There shouldn't be anything wrong there? :/

Comment: You're missing a `+`, which is confusing the compiler.  Change `+ " til " sluttStasjon +` to `+ " til " + sluttStasjon +`.

Answer (score 0):

Variable names cannot start with a digit. So, '1' is wrong variable name. Instead of

```
Linje 1=linjerMap.get(linjeList[i]);
```

you should have something like this:

```
Linje x1=linjerMap.get(linjeList[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

From [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html)

> Variable names are case-sensitive. A variable's name can be any legal
>   identifier — an unlimited-length sequence of Unicode letters and
>   digits, **beginning with a letter, the dollar sign "$", or the
>   underscore character** "*". The convention, however, is to always begin
>   your variable names with a letter, not "$" or "*". Additionally, the
>   dollar sign character, by convention, is never used at all. You may
>   find some situations where auto-generated names will contain the
>   dollar sign, but your variable names should always avoid using it. A
>   similar convention exists for the underscore character; while it's
>   technically legal to begin your variable's name with "_", this
>   practice is discouraged. White space is not permitted. Subsequent
>   characters may be letters, digits, dollar signs, or underscore
>   characters. Conventions (and common sense) apply to this rule as well.
>   When choosing a name for your variables, use full words instead of
>   cryptic abbreviations. Doing so will make your code easier to read and
>   understand. In many cases it will also make your code
>   self-documenting; fields named cadence, speed, and gear, for example,
>   are much more intuitive than abbreviated versions, such as s, c, and
>   g. Also keep in mind that the name you choose must not be a keyword or
>   reserved word. If the name you choose consists of only one word, spell
>   that word in all lowercase letters. If it consists of more than one
>   word, capitalize the first letter of each subsequent word. The names
>   gearRatio and currentGear are prime examples of this convention. If
>   your variable stores a constant value, such as static final int
>   NUM_GEARS = 6, the convention changes slightly, capitalizing every
>   letter and separating subsequent words with the underscore character.
>   By convention, the underscore character is never used elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the object from the map to a variable with the name 1 which is not allowed in Java. Instead, you need

```
Linje linje1 = linjerMap.get(linjeList[i]);
```

See here for more info: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367